# unable to find nuget for MonitorClient

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

i am trying to access monitoring data using Monitor API.

I am trying to create Monitoring Client  using this code in azure functions .net core 3.1 but no nuget seems to resolve it. Can someone suggest the correct nuget

```
    private async Task<MonitorClient> GetMonitorClientAsync()
    {
        var serviceCreds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, secret);
        var monitorClient = new MonitorClient(serviceCreds);
        monitorClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        return monitorClient;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> unable to find nuget for MonitorClient

- Use `MonitorManagementClient` in place of  `MonitorClient`
- `MonitorManagementClient` is available in the  `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor` namespace
- Install the latest `0.28.0-preview` version of  `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor`. If it is not available in the Nuget Packages, run the below command in the `Package Manager Console`

```json
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor -Version 0.28.0-preview
```

***Nuget Packages :***

[image]

***Code :***

```cs
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor;

var monitorClient = new MonitorManagementClient(serviceCreds);
```

***References taken from :***

[MonitorClient's replacement MonitorManagementClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/558)